# Uploaded file doesn't have a file owner (using move_uploaded_file in PHP)

Tags: php, file-upload, copy, move

I am using the move_uploaded_file function to upload files. The files get moved into the right directory and I see its physical existence, but I  can't open them. I get "Access Denied" error. I view the properties of the file and I found that it doesn't have an owner.

By the way, I am running IIS on Windows 2008.

I check the permissions, everything is set up correctly. The user that is running the web service has full admin rights.

Additionally, I replaced the move_uploaded_file function with copy(), and I was able to access the file. It also had the user that is running the server as its owner.

What on earth could possibly be wrong?

Thanks I appreciate your help.

**UPDATE:**
After the file is moved I tried to set permissions using chmod($filename,0655) but that didn't work either.

**UPDATE 2 (solution):**
Alright guys, I figured it out.
The system administrator didn't set the upload_tmp_dir.It worked once we added a path.

Source code:

```
         // Check if file was uploaded
     if(isset($_FILES['formname']) && $_FILES['formname']['size'] > 8){
         $displayName = $_FILES['formname']['name'];
            $displayName = unixfilename(basename($displayName));

            $tempName = $_FILES['formname']['tmp_name'];

         $filename = $_FILES['formname']['name'];
         $fileType = substr($filename, strrpos($filename,".")+1);
         $filename = substr($filename,0,strrpos($filename,".")) . date("_Ymd_His") . ".$fileType"; // Add unique identifier
         $filename = unixfilename(basename($filename)); 

         $destinationPath = "xx\yy\zz\\";

         // Check if the file is of a valid type
         if($fileType == "txt"){
             // Check if file exists in processor folder
             if(!file_exists($destinationPath.$filename)){
                if(move_uploaded_file($tempName,$destinationPath.$filename)){
                    if(file_exists($destinationPath.$filename)){
 // success
```

Answer (score 0):

check who is the  user who do the upload actually

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having `upload_tmp_dir` set in your php.ini file, ensure that the directory you set is writable by PHP.

If you're using the PHP Manager in IIS, it defaults the `upload_tmp_dir` to `C:\Windows\Temp` which was not writable by the PHP process by default for me.